# C++ where to define predicates to be used with find_if and how to generalize them

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, predicate

I would start with an example:

## ThreadManager.cpp

```
class ThreadManger{
public:
  ...
private:
  // First predicate
  class MyThreadDereferencedEqual
  {
  public:
    MyThreadDereferencedEqual(const MyThread* toFind) : toFind_(toFind) { }
    bool operator() (const MyThread* other) const { return *toFind_ == *other; }
  private:
    const MyThread* toFind_;
  };

  // Second predicate
  struct MyThreadIsCurrent
  {
    bool operator() (MyThread* theThread) const { return theThread->isCurrentThread(); }
  };

  std::vector<MyThread*>::iterator findThreadHandle(MyThread* threadHandle)
  {
    assert(threadHandle);
    return std::find_if(vThreadHandles_.begin(), vThreadHandles_.end(), MyThreadDereferencedEqual(threadHandle));
  }

  std::vector<MyThread*>::iterator findCurrentThread()
  {
    return std::find_if(vThreadHandles_.begin(), vThreadHandles_.end(), MyThreadIsCurrent());
  }
  ...
}
```

Where should I put these predicates?

1. Is it OK to leave these predicates as nested classes in the manager that uses them?
2. Should I move them to MyThreads instead? (In the end the predicates from the example are specific to MyThread, using only MyThread pointers)
3. Move them to global/custom namespace?
4. Generalize them and move them to a header for reuse?

For number 4) if I would like to generalize these predicates for reuse and make them templated I would change:

First predicate to:

```
template<typename T>
class DereferencedEqual
{
public:
    DereferencedEqual(const T* toFind) : toFind_(toFind) { }
    bool operator() (const T* other) const { return *toFind_ == *other; }
private:
    const T* toFind_;
};
```

Second predicate to:

```
// Have no idea how to make this generic ...
```

Comment: You should ask one question at a time. The first one is opinion based. The second is potentially interesting and looks answerable.

Comment: Every C++ codebase should probably eventually build up a library of useful general algorithms and predicates, since there will always be things you want that aren't covered by the standard library but that are general. I'd have no problem putting the latter template into that collection.

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about predicates - they're like any other function, class template etc. - expose them to the smallest scope that logically might profit from their use, and if they seem to have potential to be more widely useful make them accordingly more general/reusable.  Without know the greater body of code these will be plonked into we can't guess whether some of it might want to use such functionality.  Keep in mind too that with lambdas these aren't necessarily complicated enough to significantly simplify client code, and they're extra things to investigate.

Comment: @Tony D: When It comes to predicates I always find it hard to find a right place for them. If I define a predicate for searching for A* pointers than should I put them in class A? This would mean anyone including A.h would have the predicates defined... on the other hand adding a lot of nested classes looks ugly.

Comment: @CrHasher: if the predicate is only useful for `A*`s, then put it in the same header as `A`; if non-`member` non-`friend` suffices, that improves encapsulation (less code to read to understand the set of mutating operations on the class), otherwise to taste: a balancing act, like so many things in programming.  Re 2nd predicate "no idea how to make this generic" - two things you could do: make the `MyThread` class a template param, and/or the member function; for `MyThread` only, limited point as how many other classes have an `isCurrentThread()` member?  Again, I have clients use a lambda.